# Validate Radiobuttons in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

Could someone tell me please how can I get value from radiobutton to validate it?

I tried something like this:

```
binder = new Binder<>();
SelectionItemConverter selectionItemConverter = new SelectionItemConverter(radioOptions);
binder.forField(radioButtonGroup).withConverter(selectionItemConverter).asRequired("Mandatory")
.bind(e -> getValue(), (b, v) -> setValue(v));
binder.setBean(this);
```

Firstly I started with asRequired("Mandatory") Validator but I dont see a red asteriks next to my field. Does anybody know a good tutorial about diffrent than string validation form?

Comment: Have you tried `setRequiredIndicatorVisible(true);` to achieve red asteriks?
Take look at this example wtih [DateValidator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46604363/vaadin-datefield-validation-does-not-show-validation-errors/46647837#46647837)

Comment: @avix I believe that should've been covered by [`asRequired("Mandatory")`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.1/8.1.5/docs/api/com/vaadin/data/Binder.BindingBuilder.html#asRequired-java.lang.String-). @Anna Are you using any custom theme and can you share a full example? I just made a quick sample using an enum with Vaadin 8.1.5 and it works just fine. Also, the [Vaadin docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/datamodel/datamodel-forms.html#datamodel.forms.validation) related to validation are usually a good source of information.

Answer (score 0):

Radio button value you can validate with normal validator. If you are using enum values then you cannot validate user input because user can choose between valid values.

If you wish to validate enum value against some other field then you can add a validator that compares current value of the field to some other field. It is important to remember to add a value change listener to the binder to trigger validation if the second field changes.

```
RadioButtonGroup<RadioSelection> radioButtonGroup = new RadioButtonGroup<>("Answer");
radioButtonGroup.setItems(RadioSelection.values());
binder.forField(radioButtonGroup)
        .asRequired("Mandatory")
        .withValidator(value -> !(isToday(dateField) && value == RadioSelection.MAYBE),
                "Cannot answer MAYBE today")
        .bind(MyBean::getRadioSelection, MyBean::setRadioSelection);
binder.addValueChangeListener(v -> binder.validate());
```

Also read in [Book of Vaadin about validation](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/datamodel/datamodel-forms.html).

Enum used in the example is

```
public enum RadioSelection {
    YES, NO, MAYBE
}
```